# Increase throughput in network load heavy topology storm with dynamo

Tags: bigdata, amazon-dynamodb, apache-storm

I have a topology running on aws. I use M3 xlarge machines with 15GB ram, 8 supervisors. My topology is simple, I read from 
kafka spout  -> [db o/p1] -> [db o/p2] -> [dynamo fetch] -> [dynamo write & kafka write] kafka

db o/ps are conditional. with latency around 100 - 150 ms.

But I have never been able to achieve a throughput of more than 300 msgs/sec.

What configuration changes are to be made so that I can get a throughput of more than 3k msgs/sec?

dynamo fetch bolt execute latency is around 150 - 220ms
and dynamo read bolt execute latency is also around this number.

four bolts with parallelism 90 each and one spout with parallelism 30 (30 kafka partitions)

overall latency is greater than 4 secs.

`topology.message.timeout.secs: 600
worker.childopts: "-Xmx5120m
no. of worker ports per machine : 2`

`no of workers : 6
no of threads : 414
executor send buffer size 16384
executor receive buffer size 16384
transfer buffer size: 34
no of ackers: 24`

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?  Start with posting the capacity of the bolts according to the Storm UI console.

Comment: without a screenshot of storm UI it will very hard any1 help you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn92ufikwzmiz9d/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-07%20at%205.05.57%20pm.png?dl=0 - Link to snapshot

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the console snapshot I see...

1) The overall latency for the Spout is much greater than the sum of the execute latencies of the bolts, which implies that there's a backlog on one of the streams, and

2) The capacity for SEBolt is much higher that that of the other bolts, implying that Storm feels the need to run that bolt more than the others

So I think your bottleneck is the SEBolt.  Look into increasing the parallelism hint on that one.  If the total number of tasks is getting too high, reduce the parallelism hint for the other bolts to offset the increase for SEBolt.

Comment: The overall latency in storm - could that be because of the buffer size I chose? _From my calculations I feel that I should run around 400 threads and the max pipeline latency to be 70 ms to be able to achieve the desired throughput._ So if I decrease the buffer sizes, and increase the threads and workers, would that help?

Comment: I would increase the SEBolt parallelism hint, rerun the topology and see if that had any positive effect for the overall latency and SEBolt capacity.  Then revert the change and change the buffer sizes from 16384 to 8192 then check the Storm UI console.  Keep halving the buffer size as long as you see improvements in the metrics.